# babel-plugin-react-intl: Extract strings to a single file

Tags: react-intl

Currently while using `babel-plugin-react-intl`, separate json for every component is created with 'id', 'description' and 'defaultMessage'. What I need is that only a single json to be created which contains a single object with all the 'id' as the 'key' and 'defaultMessage' as the 'value'

Present situation:

`ComponentA.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": "addEmoticonA",
    "description": "Add emoticon",
    "defaultMessage": "Insert Emoticon"
  },
  {
    "id": "addPhotoA",
    "description": "Add photo",
    "defaultMessage": "Insert photo"
  }
]
```

`ComponentB.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": "addEmoticonB",
    "description": "Add emoji",
    "defaultMessage": "Insert Emoji"
  },
  {
    "id": "addPhotoB",
    "description": "Add picture",
    "defaultMessage": "Insert picture"
  }
]
```

What I need for translation.

`final.json`

```
{
  "addEmoticonA": "Insert Emoticon",
  "addPhotoA": "Insert photo",
  "addEmoticonB": "Insert Emoji",
  "addPhotoB": "Insert picture"
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task? May it be by using python script or anything. i.e to make a single json file from different json files. Or to directly make a single json file using babel-plugin-react-intl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [translations manager](https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-intl-translations-manager)  that will do this.

Or for a custom option see below

---

The script below which is based on this [script](https://github.com/emmenko/redux-react-router-async-example/blob/master/scripts/i18nToXliff.js) goes through the translation messages created by
`babel-plugin-react-intl` and creates js files that contain all messages from all components in the json format.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import {
  sync as globSync
}
from 'glob'
import {
  sync as mkdirpSync
}
from 'mkdirp'
import * as i18n from '../lib/i18n'

const MESSAGES_PATTERN = './_translations/**/*.json'
const LANG_DIR         = './_translations/lang/'
  // Ensure output folder exists
mkdirpSync(LANG_DIR)

// Aggregates the default messages that were extracted from the example app's
// React components via the React Intl Babel plugin. An error will be thrown if
// there are messages in different components that use the same `id`. The result
// is a flat collection of `id: message` pairs for the app's default locale.
let defaultMessages = globSync(MESSAGES_PATTERN)
  .map(filename => fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'))
  .map(file => JSON.parse(file))
  .reduce((collection, descriptors) => {
    descriptors.forEach(({
      id, defaultMessage, description
    }) => {
      if (collection.hasOwnProperty(id))
        throw new Error(`Duplicate message id: ${id}`)

      collection[id] = {
        defaultMessage, description
      }
    })
    return collection
  }, {})

// Sort keys by name
const messageKeys = Object.keys(defaultMessages)
messageKeys.sort()
defaultMessages = messageKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = defaultMessages[key]
  return acc
}, {})

// Build the JSON document for the available languages
i18n.en = messageKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = defaultMessages[key].defaultMessage
  return acc
}, {})
Object.keys(i18n).forEach(lang => {
  const langDoc = i18n[lang]
  const units = Object.keys(defaultMessages).map((id) => [id, defaultMessages[id]]).reduce((collection, [id]) => {
    collection[id] = langDoc[id] || '';
    return collection;
  }, {});
  fs.writeFileSync(`${LANG_DIR}${lang}.json`, JSON.stringify(units, null, 2))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [babel-plugin-react-intl-extractor](https://github.com/Bolid1/babel-plugin-react-intl-extractor) for aggregate your translations in single file. Also it provides autorecompile translation files on each change of your messages.